# Gridview keep search while paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a textbox where I write a word to search in the gridview. The research works well for the first page of my gridview, but when I go to another page the research resets.

Here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.IO;


public partial class _Default : Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.BindData();
        }
    }


    private void BindData()
    {
        string query = "select * from Ressources";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();      
    }


    private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    protected void EditCustomer(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        this.BindData();
    }


    protected void CancelEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        BindData();

    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindData();
    }


    private void BindData(string Query)
    {
        string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(Query + ";select * from Ressources", conn))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }


    protected void RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (GridView1.EditIndex >= 0)
            return;

        if ((e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Normal || e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate) &&
        (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header))
        {
            e.Row.Cells[3].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[4].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[6].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[7].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[8].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[10].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[14].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[15].Visible = false;
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }


    private void AddNewRecord(string URL, string Type_Source, string First_date, string Data, string Crawler_subcategory)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "select * from Ressources where data like'%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

}
```

The function used to search the word is named btnSearch_Click().

I would appreciate your help.

Thank you !

Comment: The research resets ? If i am not wrong you want the searched resultset to persist during paging? Right ? If so than create two query for  operations, to maintain state keep text value in viewstate and check for its null or empty according to viewstate value fill your gridview.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dataview and rowfilter. You could also choose to cache the OriginalDataTable in a sessionvariable.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    // Hold the original datatable from database
    System.Data.DataTable OriginalDataTable = null; 

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            BindGridView("");
    }

    void BindGridView(string searchQuery )
    {

        GridView1.DataSource = GetSelectionResult(searchQuery);
        GridView1.DataBind(); 

    }

    private void initialData()
    {
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["defaultconnection"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "select * from Ressources";

        OriginalDataTable = new DataTable(); 

        using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString))
        {
            dataAdapter.Fill(OriginalDataTable); 
        }

    }


    DataView GetSelectionResult(string searchParam)
    {
        if (OriginalDataTable == null)
            initialData();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchParam))
            return OriginalDataTable.DefaultView;

        string rowFilter = string.Format("data like '%{0}%'", searchParam);
        return new DataView(OriginalDataTable, rowFilter, "data", DataViewRowState.OriginalRows); 

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindGridView(TextBox1.Text); 
    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //...
    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindGridView(TextBox1.Text); 
    }

}
```

In the case of caching the datatable into a sessionvariable:

```
private void initialData()
{
    string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["defaultconnection"].ConnectionString;
    string query = "select * from Ressources";

    if (Session["datatableinsession"] == null)
    {        
        OriginalDataTable = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString))
        {
            dataAdapter.Fill(OriginalDataTable);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        OriginalDataTable = Session["datatableinsession"] as DataTable;
    }

}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     BindData();

    }
    Private xxx BindData()
    {
     if(Viewstate[txt] !==null)
         {
          string WhereCl= GetWhereClause(txt);
         }
        string query = "select * from Ressources";
         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(WhereCl))
       { 
         query =query + WhereCl;
       }         
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    Private string GetWhereClause(string txt)
    {
      string where  = where data like'%" + txt+ "%'";
    }
```

Call this binding method on paging also .
Hope this helps ..

Answer (score 0):

isn't it faster to just save the search parameter in session, check if it is inside and search it again (since it seems your text data isn't saved)

Comment: Well it will be much good if we use Viewstate for storing text data.

Answer (score 0):

Declare separate method as

```
private void Search()
{
string query = "select * from Ressources where data like'%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Call `Search()` on page index chenging as

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        Search();
    }
```

And you can call the same method on search button click.

```
public void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Search();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create only one Method to Bind The Data as below:

```
private void BindData()
    {
        string query = "";
        if (txtSearch.Text != "" &&  txtSearch.Text != string.Empty) {
            query = "select * from Ressources where data like'%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'";                 
        } else {
             query = "select * from Ressources";
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Thats all